# Using Monte Carlo method to estimate the value of $\int_0^1\int_0^1e^{xy} \ dx \ dy$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, monte-carlo

> Monte Carlo, estimate the value of $$\int_0^1\int_0^1e^{xy} \ dx \ dy.$$

I am using matlab to solve this problem. My code is the following:

```
A = 1;  
N = 100000;  
s = 0;  
for i = 1:N;  
    x = rand; 
    y = rand;  
    z = rand;  
    if z <= exp(x*y);  
        s = s + 1;  
    end;  
end;  
I=A*s/N
```

The problem is that every time I run this script I get an answer of I = $1$. In fact, whatever I initialize the area (in this case volume) to be is what gets returned as the answer. As a visual aid, I attempted to graph $e^{xy}$.

[image]

Now, this code is an adaptation of a code I wrote for a previous problem I was working on. That problem was to use the Monte Carlo method to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}x^2dx$ in matlab. My code for that problem was the following:

```
A=1; 
N=10000; 
s=0; 
for i=1:N 
    x=rand; 
    y=rand; 
        if y<= x^2; 
            s=s+1; 
        end; 
end; 
I=A*s/N
```

This code was successful, and, as I increased the value for N, it became increasingly more accurate, as expected. However, when I make the jump from the single integral to the double integral, something in my code is not translating properly.

Comment: If $rand$ is a random number in $[0,1]$ then $z \leq e^{xy}$ is always true as $e^{xy}\geq 1$. This would explain the answer.

Comment: Also when using MC integration are you not supposed to just add the random samples, i.e. $s = s + e^{xy}$ and not have the if test?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} e^{xy} dxdy = \gamma + Ei(1) \approx 1.317902151$. Here $\gamma$ is the Euler's gamma constant, and $Ei(x)$ is the exponential integral function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code that should do the trick:

```
s=0;
for i=1:N  
x=rand(0,1); 
y=rand(0,1);
s=s+exp(xy); 
end 
I = s/N;
```